# Inequality for adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I am working with the wave equation and energy inequalities in certain Hilbert space different from $H^{0}$.

In particular, I have an energy estimate of the form $\Arrowvert\phi\Arrowvert\le\Arrowvert\square\phi\Arrowvert$. I am interested in proving:

$$\Arrowvert\square\phi\Arrowvert\le\Arrowvert\square^{*}\phi\Arrowvert$$.

In general, is there a relationship between the norm of an operator and its adjoint acting on Hilbert spaces?

Answer (score 0):

For bounded operators, the norm of the adjoint is the same as the "original" operator, as a consequence of the Riesz' theorem. The point is that $\square$ is tipically unbounded and one have to concern about the domain. Physically, however, energy is a measurable quantity, therefore is represented by a self-adjoint operator on the Hilbert space of the theory. So, I can't see any real problem in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined a domain $\mathcal{D}(\Box)$ for $\Box$ so that $(\Box f,g)=(f,\Box g)$ for all $f,g \in \mathcal{D}(\Box)$, then $\Box^{\star}$ is an extension of $\Box$, which means that $\Box f = \Box^{\star}f $ on the common domain. Exactly how have you defined the domain?